# Can $(AA^T)^{-1}A$ be simplified?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, where $m<n$, can the expression $(AA^T)^{-1}A$ be simplified?

Comment: @SamStreeter Is there a formula for the inverse of the product of *non-square* matrices?

Comment: Short answer: no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(AA^T)^{-1}A$ is the [Moore–Penrose inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) of $A^T$. The expression cannot be simplified in general.

Answer (score 0):

In general no, but you could express it in different terms. One instance of what I say is [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition), so doing the decomposition for $A^T$ $$A^T = QR$$
You will get
$$(AA^T)^{-1}A = (R^TQ^TQR)^{-1}R^TQ^T = (R^TR)^{-1}R^TQ^T$$